# Update SQLite database rows from JTextField not working, no changes to db at all. all Connections are fine and previously used ones are closed

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sqlite, jdbc

I am making a GUI application( payroll system ) using Java Swing and SQLite.       My problem is when I try to Update SQLite database rows from JTextField, it does not do any changes to the database. But my Insert, View and Delete functions are working fine.
Please help. Previously open connection, pst's and resultsets are closed after use.

```
JButton btnUpdate = new JButton("Update");
    btnUpdate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            try{

                String val1=name.getText();
                String val2=e_id.getText();
                String val3=email.getText();
                String val4=emp_type.getText();
                String val5=desig.getText();
                String val6=dept.getText();
                String val7=sex.getText();
                String val8=h_no.getText();
                String val9=st_name.getText();
                String val10=city.getText();
                String val11=state.getText();
                String val12=pin_code.getText();

                String val14=report_to.getText();
                String val15=a_sal.getText();
                String val16=bonus.getText();
                String val17=m_sal.getText();
                String val18=emp_sr.getText();

                String sql="update emp set     e_id='"+val2+"',name='"+name.getText()+"', email='"+val3+"',emp_type='"+val4+"',desig='"+val5+"',"
                        + "dept='"+val6+"',sex='"+val7+"',h_no='"+val8+"', st_name = '"+val9+"', city = '"+val10+"', "
                                + "state ='"+val11+"',pin_code ='"+val12+"', report_to ='"+val14+"', a_sal ='"+val15+"', "
                                        + "bonus ='"+val16+"', m_sal ='"+val17+"' where e_id='"+emp_sr.getText()+"' ";

                PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(sql);

                pst.executeUpdate();

            }catch(Exception e1) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Updated");

            }finally{}
        }
    });
```

Comment: try to print your query and check with your db whether the condition statement works? If you are facing any exception post your stack trace

Comment: e_id='"+emp_sr.getText() ? 
e_id =e_id.getText() !

Comment: `emp_sr.getText()` why use that inside your sql string if you already stored it in a variable?

Comment: The fact you show "Record Updated" in case of an exception is rather suspicious... You might want to print the exception instead. And, please, use a prepared statement correctly, **do not concatenate values into a query string**. Use parameters.